# Strongly typed TemplateRef

Tags: angular

Angular documentation says `TemplateRef` requires type argument. It works by adding `any`, but is it possible to type it more closely?

Parent component:

```html
<div [summaryTemplate]="summaryTemplateRef”></div>

<ng-template #summaryTemplateRef let-total="total" let-limit="limit">
  <div>
    Total items: {{ total }}
  </div>
  <div>
    page: {{ limit }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Child component:

```js
@Input() summaryTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

```html
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="summaryTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ total: data.length, limit: limit }">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Just use `TemplateRef<{total: number, limit: number}>`? What exactly are you looking to type other than the context?

Comment: Oh, I thought it is much more complicated than `TemplateRef<{total: number, limit: number}>`. Thanks for that!